# Oracle value caching on view generation?

Tags: sql, oracle, view, oracle10g

I have two tables STATEMENT and TRANSACTION, which I'd like to create a view on.  Both tables have ID (VARCHAR2) and TS (NUMBER).

For each ID, STATEMENT is generated every month, based on TRANSACTION and other tables.

The view has 3 columns: ID, TS, and VALUE.  Each row in the view corresponds to a row in STATEMENT, and VALUE is a rather complex aggregation depending on both STATEMENT and TRANSACTION.

Specifically, the portion of VALUE retrieved from TRANSACTION is constant for each ID, regardless of TS.

Since this aggregated value does not change, does Oracle automatically cache it?  If not, is it possible to cache the values somewhere, for example, by creating an intermediate view for this value?

Answer (score 3):

Non-materialized views are not cached -- they are merely contained SQL statements that are run when a reference is made in a statement that is being executed.  Think of them like a macro, or variable for the statement the view contains.  So there's no performance value to layering views -- having one reference another.

Oracle supports materialized views, but [materialized views are notoriously restrictive](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10500_01/server.920/a96567/repmview.htm) -- no non-deterministic functions, etc.

To tell the difference, `CREATE VIEW` creates a non-materialized view.  Oracle requires the MATERIALIZED keyword: `CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW ...` for the view to be materialized.